# Using IP.Board XML-RPC API

Tags: ipb

I write the application on Node.js and I need to get information from the forum, which works on the engine IP.Board. I decided to use XML-RPC API. On this issue there is an article [In the administrative tools  set support for XML-RPC API](https://www.invisionpower.com/support/guides/_/advanced-and-developers/api-methods/xml-rpc-api-r62) on the website of the IPB.  I managed to get some information through the API, but I don't know how to authenticate a user.

My actions:

1. In the administrative tools  set support for XML-RPC API
2. Add user and allow to perform all methods
3. Copy the key and use in my application

But when it comes to posting on the forum from outside I have trouble . Read the article linked above:

method postTopic

- member_field: This should be the field to look up the 'member_key' in
  (for instance, 'member_id', 'email', 'members_display_name', etc.)
- member_key: The value to search in 'member_field' with in order to find the poster. You may pass member_field as ID and member_key as
  1, for instance, to post a topic as member ID 1.
- forum_id: The ID of the forum to post the topic in
- topic_title: The topic title
- post_content: The contents of the first post

Now I need to know the ID of the user on whose behalf to publish a post. How to know this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and simple solution is not found. You can write your extension for IPB and implement the necessary APIs themselves. Using IPB XML-RPC API (at the time of publication of the question), you can only yourself to find out the ID of a user and on his behalf to make the publication, publish answers or use other available options. For example, automatically check the availability of offensive language in the message and answer any warning.